# I Cannot bind to the property or column itemDescription on the DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, winforms

When I press the login and call the LoginClick() method, the exception occurs, this happened after I changed the column name from my SQL database using SSMS  from 'itemDescription' to 'itemName' I hope you can help me. I have tried everything and make sure that I researched before asking this question. I am stuck here for hours now. I do not know where is the problem.

LoginForm.cs

```
private void LoginClick()
    {
        if (MTBoxUsername.Text.Length == 0 || MTBoxPassword.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username and password", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(MTBoxUsername.Text, out int j))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your username is your student number", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }
            string username = MTBoxUsername.Text;
            string password = MTBoxPassword.Text;
            var student = (from s in DatabaseHelper.db.tblUsers
                           where s.username == long.Parse(username)
                           select s).First();
            if (student != null)
            {
                if (BCrypt.CheckPassword(password, student.password))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Succesful!", "INFORMATION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.Hide();
                    if (student.userType.Equals("STUDENT"))
                    {
                        var loginStudent = (from s in DatabaseHelper.db.tblStudents
                                            where s.StudentNumber == long.Parse(username)
                                            select s).First();
                        new StudentForm().Show();
                    }
                    else if (student.userType.Equals("ADMIN"))
                    {
                        new AdminForm().Show();
                    }
                    else if (student.userType.Equals("FACULTY"))
                    {
                        new StaffFormMain().Show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
    }
```

StudentForm.cs

```
public StudentForm()
    {
        this.selectedStudent = (from s in DatabaseHelper.db.tblStudents
                               where s.StudentNumber == 2000013113
                               select s).First();
        InitializeComponent();
        materialSkinManager = MaterialSkin.MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
        materialSkinManager.EnforceBackcolorOnAllComponents = true;
        materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
        materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkin.MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;
        materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new MaterialSkin.ColorScheme(MaterialSkin.Primary.Indigo500,
            MaterialSkin.Primary.Indigo700,
            MaterialSkin.Primary.Indigo100,
            MaterialSkin.Accent.Pink200,
            MaterialSkin.TextShade.WHITE);
    }

    private void RefreshCartList()
    {
        DgvCartList.Rows.Clear();
        subTotal = 0;
        foreach (OrderDetail item in cartList)
        {
            DgvCartList.Rows.Add(item.itemName,
                item.quantity,
                item.pricePerUnit,
                item.total);
            subTotal += item.total;
        }
        BtnCheckout.Enabled = cartList.Count > 0;
        BtnClearCart.Enabled = cartList.Count > 0;
        BtnRemoveItem.Enabled = cartList.Count > 0;
        LabelSubTotal.Text = cartList.Count > 0 ? subTotal.ToString() : "";
    }

    private void ClearCart()
    {
        cartList.Clear();
        RefreshCartList();
    }

    private void CmbItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelStockCount.Text = itemList[CmbItems.SelectedIndex].stocks.ToString();
        LabelPrice.Text = itemList[CmbItems.SelectedIndex].price.ToString();
        BtnAddToCart.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void BtnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CmbItems.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            tblItem selectedItem = itemList[CmbItems.SelectedIndex];

            if (cartList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (OrderDetail item in cartList)
                {
                    if (item.itemID.Equals(selectedItem.ID))
                    {
                        if (item.quantity == 99)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You cannot add more than 99 items of the same type in cart.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (item.quantity == selectedItem.stocks)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You have reached the maximum number of stocks available.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            return;
                        }
                        item.quantity++;
                        RefreshCartList();
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }
            cartList.Add(new OrderDetail
            {
                itemID = selectedItem.ID,
                itemName = selectedItem.itemName,
                quantity = 1,
                pricePerUnit = selectedItem.price
            });
            RefreshCartList();


        }
    }

    private void DgvCartList_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedItemFromCart = DgvCartList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }

    private void BtnRemoveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove '" + selectedItemFromCart + "' from your cart?",
            "QUESTION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            foreach (OrderDetail item in cartList)
            {
                if (item.itemName.Equals(selectedItemFromCart))
                {
                    cartList.Remove(item);
                    RefreshCartList();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void BtnClearCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to clear your cart?", "QUESTION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ClearCart();
        }
    }

    private void BtnCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to checkout? You cannot reverse this action once done.", "QUESTION", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            var newOrder = new tblOrder
            {
                studentId = selectedStudent.StudentNumber,
                orderStatus = "PENDING",
                orderDate = DateTime.Today.Date,
                totalPrice = subTotal

            };
            DatabaseHelper.db.tblOrders.InsertOnSubmit(newOrder);
            DatabaseHelper.db.SubmitChanges();

            var st = (from tbl in itemList
                     join cart in cartList on tbl.ID equals cart.itemID
                     select new { 
                         tbl.ID,
                         cart.quantity
                     }).ToList();

            foreach(var item in st)
            {
                var reduceStock = (from s in DatabaseHelper.db.tblItems
                                  where s.ID == item.ID
                                  select s).First();
                reduceStock.stocks -= item.quantity;
                
            }

            DatabaseHelper.db.SubmitChanges();

            foreach (OrderDetail item in cartList)
            {
                var newOrderDetail = new tblOrderDetail
                {
                    orderIdRef = newOrder.ID,
                    itemID = item.itemID,
                    itemName = item.itemName,
                    quantity = item.quantity,
                    pricePerUnit = item.pricePerUnit,
                    totalPrice = item.total,
                    orderStatus = "PENDING"

                };
                DatabaseHelper.db.tblOrderDetails.InsertOnSubmit(newOrderDetail);
            }
            DatabaseHelper.db.SubmitChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Order placed!", "INFORMATION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            MessageBox.Show("Please save this document and/or print it and show it to the cashier.", "INFORMATION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            using (PrintForm frm = new PrintForm())
            {
                frm.PrintInvoice(newOrder.studentId,
                fullName.Trim(),
                newOrder.ID,
                newOrder.orderDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
                subTotal,
                cartList);
                frm.ShowDialog();
            }
            ClearCart();
            
        }
    }

    private void MStudentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelStudentNum.Text = selectedStudent.StudentNumber.ToString();
        
        if (selectedStudent.MiddleName.ToString().Length == 0)
        {
            fullName = selectedStudent.FirstName.ToString() + " " + selectedStudent.LastName.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            fullName = selectedStudent.FirstName.ToString() + " " + selectedStudent.MiddleName.ToString() + " " + selectedStudent.LastName.ToString();
        }
        LabelName.Text = fullName.Trim();
        LabelCourse.Text = selectedStudent.Course.ToString();
        LabelGender.Text = selectedStudent.Gender.ToString();

        switch (selectedStudent.Course.ToString())
        {
            case "BSIT":
                courseCategory = "IT";
                break;
            case "BSHM":
                courseCategory = "HM";
                break;
            case "BSTM":
                courseCategory = "TM";
                break;
            case "BACOMM":
                courseCategory = "AB";
                break;
        }

        var allItems = from item in DatabaseHelper.db.tblItems
                       where item.category == courseCategory
                       || item.category == "General"
                       || item.gender == selectedStudent.Gender
                       select item;

        foreach (var item in allItems)
        {
            tblItem item1 = new tblItem();
            item1.ID = item.ID;
            item1.itemName = item.itemName + " " + item.size;
            item1.category = item.category;
            item1.size = item.size;
            item1.price = item.price;
            item1.stocks = item.stocks;
            if (item1.stocks > 0)
                itemList.Add(item1);
            else
                notAvailableItemsList.Add(item1.itemName);
        }

        itemList = itemList.OrderBy(y => y.itemName).ToList();
        notAvailableItemsList = notAvailableItemsList.OrderBy(y => y).ToList();
        
        if(notAvailableItemsList.Count > 0)
        {
            string items = "";
            foreach(string item in notAvailableItemsList)
            {
                items += item;
                items += "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Not available items are:\n" + items, "INFORMATION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            CmbItems.Items.Add(item.itemName);
        }
    }

    private void MStudentForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to sign out?", "SIGN OUT", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.Hide();
            new LoginForm(false).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    private void DgvCartList_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            string name = DgvCartList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            int stockItem = 0;
            foreach (var item in itemList)
            {
                if (name.Equals(item.itemName))
                {
                    stockItem = item.stocks;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (DgvCartList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot leave this field empty.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                RefreshCartList();
                return;
            }

            int quantity = int.Parse(DgvCartList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());

            if (quantity > 99)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot add more than 99 items of the same type in cart.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                RefreshCartList();
                return;
            }
            if (quantity > stockItem)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have reached the maximum number of stocks available.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                RefreshCartList();
                return;
            }
            foreach (OrderDetail item in cartList)
            {
                if (item.itemName.Equals(name))
                {
                    item.quantity = int.Parse(DgvCartList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    RefreshCartList();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Error

```
    System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>ProwareSystem.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Cannot bind to the property or column itemDescription on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetBindingManagerBase(BindingManagerBase lManager)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.UpdateBinding(BindingContext newBindingContext, Binding binding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_BindingContextInternal(BindingContext value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.set_BindingContext(BindingContext value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.get_BindingContext()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContext()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the property or column itemDescription on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.SetBindingManagerBase(BindingManagerBase lManager)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Binding.SetListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManagerBase)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListManagerBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding dataBinding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding binding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.UpdateBinding(BindingContext newBindingContext, Binding binding)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_BindingContextInternal(BindingContext value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.set_BindingContext(BindingContext value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.get_BindingContext()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContextInternal()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_BindingContext()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Cannot bind to the property or column itemDescription on the DataSource.
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear and you practically answered this yourself: check all your files - escpecially your XAMLfiles - there should still be a "itemDescription" that needs to be renamed to "itemName". You should really think about your table definitions and make them as invariable as possible to avoid this kind of workload in the future.
P.S. this kind of question might be better suited for Stackexchanges' Code Review

Comment: I use linq to sql DBML file and I cannot find such thing. I think it is auto updated when I try to refresh it, but it seems that I cannot find where is the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I just have to change the Databindings in my designer.cs from "itemDescription" to "itemName".

I solved it by this line of code.

```
this.CmbItems.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.tblItemBindingSource, "itemName", true));
```

I want to thank everyone for sharing their knowledge.